# How do I call GNU m4 nested function?

Tags: templates, macros, gnu, m4

I am trying to define a conditional macro within macro and pass it as an option, so far I have:

**main.m4**

```
changequote([,])

define([FUNCTION_CALL],[$1    $2    $3])
```

then I do:

**basic.m4**

```
ifdef([SECURITY],
    FUNCTION_CALL([foo],[bar],[baz])
  )

FUNCTION_CALL([foo2],[bar2],[baz3]
```

and call **m4 -DSECURITY main.m4 basic.m4**

What I want:

- remove all the blank spaces crop up in the resulting file between conditional and unconditional lines
- somehow wrap `ifdef` calls into the `FUNCTION_CALL_IF` function so I do not have to write ifdef blocks all the time.

Comment: Maybe you can want to use `dnl` at end of lines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `dnl` at the end of lines, otherwise the newlines are copied to the output. So, for example:

```
ifdef([SECURITY],dnl
FUNCTION_CALL([foo],[bar],[baz])dnl
)dnl
```

Also note that I chose not to indent `FUNCTION_CALL` -- otherwise the indentation spaces also get copied to the output. An alternative is to use quote characters to create useless empty strings for indentation:

```
ifdef([SECURITY],dnl
[][]FUNCTION_CALL([foo],[bar],[baz])dnl
)dnl
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to get used to this, though.

As to your second question, creating a `FUNCTION_CALL_IF` macro:

```
define([FUNCTION_CALL_IF],[ifdef([$1],[FUNCTION_CALL([$2],[$3],[$4])])])
```

I'm not exactly sure what `FUNCTION_CALL` is for (it just adds spaces between its arguments?), but this will call it conditionally and can be used like `FUNCTION_CALL_IF([SECURITY], [foo], [bar], [baz])`

Answer (score 0):

M4 reads its input and expands macro calls as it goes. Whitespace characters are just copied to output except in certain cases. Please, read the M4 documentation to know the basics.

That being said, your issue is unclear.

Unquoted white-space characters preceding each argument is discarded and output diverted to a stream with a negative number is discarded (as you can see below).

```
divert(`-1')
changequote(`[',`]')
define([FUNCTION_CALL], [$1    $2    $3])
divert[]dnl
ifdef([SECURITY], 

  [FUNCTION_CALL([foo],[bar],[baz])],

        [FUNCTION_CALL([foo2],[bar2],[baz3])])
```